# Adding a class to a URL object

Tags: theming

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_menu_local_tasks(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables["primary"]["entity.node.edit_form"]["#link"]["url"])) {
    $url = $variables["primary"]["entity.node.edit_form"]["#link"]["url"];
    assert($url instanceof Url);
    $nid = $url->getRouteParameters()['node'];
    $node = Node::load($nid);
    if (_mytheme_some_condition($node)) {
      $attributes = (array) $url->getOption('attributes');
      $attributes['class'][] = 'little-red-riding-hood';
      $url->setOption('attributes', $attributes);
    }
  }
}
```

That's just awful. Surely there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class to

```
...['#link']['localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'foo';
```

The Link and Url options are merged in the Link render element.

Comment: `template_preprocess_menu_local_task` and `template_preprocess_menu_local_action` copies `localized_options` into `#options` for the `Link` Render element and that is indeed merged in there like this: `$options = NestedArray::mergeDeep($element['#url']->getOptions(), $element['#options']);` I saw the empty `localized_options` array in the debugger but I had no idea what it did and it's completely undocumented as far as I can see. Thanks! So this solution only works for these two kind of links, normal `'#type' => 'link'` render arrays should use  `#options`.

Comment: Yes, `'#type' => 'link'` is the render element I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you like this more. Alternatively, you could add a [menu-local-task.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21menu-local-task.html.twig/8.0.x) and do something like

```
{% if condition %}
  <li{{ attributes.addClass('little-red-riding-hood' }}>{{ link }}</li>
{% else %}
  <li{{ attributes }}>{{ link }}</li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That puts the class on `<li>` not the `<a>`.

Comment: @̷c̷h̷x̷ You could still target with `.little-red-riding-hood a`. Though if you need to load the Node object for your check, might as well stick with your preprocess approach I guess.